# Parameter being removed from query string on mobile devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile

I have a parameter being passed in a QueryString using a Response.Redirect to the url with '?type=' and the type being added. It works fine on desktop browsers, but removes the query string and parameter when viewed on a mobile device. It doesn't seem to be browser or OS specific. Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Edited to show code:
Thanks for the replies. So here is more info and what's happening in the code:

```
protected void ContinueLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string moduleType = null;
        if (CourseTypeButton.Checked)
        {
            moduleType = CourseType.Course.ToString();
        }
        else if (EventTypeButton.Checked)
        {
            moduleType = CourseType.Event.ToString();
        }
        else if (SkillsChecklistButton.Checked)
        {
            moduleType = CourseType.SkillsChecklist.ToString();
        }
        else if (RequirementTrackerTypeButton.Checked)
        {
            moduleType = CourseType.RequirementsTracker.ToString();
        }

        Response.Redirect("~/Learning/Course.aspx?type=" + moduleType);
    }
```

**Additionally, the ContinueLinkButton is in a popup.** So when you click the continue button on a mobile device, it just closes the popup and takes you back to the original screen the popup window opens from instead of going to the new page.

Comment: No it does not happen. Please make sure to provide some sort of evidence of the behavior in your post (like result of Fiddler trace or IIS logs or ...) or maybe code that shows the behavior.

Comment: is there any restriction on the length of the url in mobile browser? Maybe you logic depends on the client ( desktop or mobile) and the mobile path logic might be doing something wrong

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need some sample code in order to understand the problem better, perhaps from your controller that is sending the query string.

Comment: Updated to show code and with more info. Thanks!